# Is there a method to expand matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this

```
Mt = matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0),2,3)
```

what I wanna do is add two more rows below, but these two rows have to have relationship with the above rows. For example, the third and fourth row have a relationship with the first row, it will have a probability  p to become 1 1 where the first row is 1 [they inherit the 0], and (1-p)/2 to become 1 0 or 0 1 where the first row is 1, last Mt is in a 4*3 size. The same rule applies if the two rows have relationship with the second row, i need to randomly choose which row should be related to the new two extra rows.
A new to R, and I even don't know how to search for it. I appreciate for any help.

Comment: This is confusing to me. You say that rows 3-4 should be based off of row 1, which I think I understand, but based on your probability rules, I see no way to include row 2 into the determination of rows 3-4. I think what you're saying is something like this: for each *column*, randomly choose one of rows 1-2, use your probability heuristics to assign values to rows 3-4. Is that right? Next step: both of your conditions say *"first row is 1"*; if the row 1 (or row 2) value is 0, then  both rows 3-4 are value 0?

Comment: Yes! Your understanding is right! @r2evans. Randomly choose row 1 or 2 then apply that rules to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, though I'm not sure if I have your rules correct:

```r
func <- function(p) {
  ps <- c(p, (1-p)/2)
  opts <- c(
    list(
      list(c(1,1)),         # p
      list(c(1,0), c(0,1))  # (1-p)/2
    )[order(ps)],
    list(list(c(NA, NA)))   # not within the other two, always last
  )
  out <- opts[[ findInterval(runif(1), c(-Inf, sort(ps), Inf)) ]]
  if (length(out) == 1) out[[1]] else out[[ sample(length(out), 1) ]]
}
```

From here, we `apply` over the columns:

```r
set.seed(42)
newrows <- apply(Mt, 2, function(col) {
  onerow <- sample(col, size = 1)
  if (onerow == 0) return(c(0, 0))
  func(p = 0.7)
})
newrows
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    1
# [2,]    0    1    1
```

(Do not use `set.seed` in production, it's just to reproduce exactly what we see here.)

We can combine these with the original data with

```r
rbind(Mt, newrows)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    1
# [4,]    0    1    1
```

Notes:

- You mentioned *"inherit 0"*, so the new rows are always `0,0` if the randomly-chosen original row is a 0. Because we've exhausted the possibilities with `0,0`, `1,1`, or one of `0,1`/`1,0`, then ...
- If a random number (`runif`) is not among `p` (returning `1,1`) and `(1-p)/2` (returning one of `1,0` or `0,1`, randomly), then it should return something else. In this case, I've chosen `NA,NA`, though that is purely to show that not always is a `1` included; you can change this "last option" by updating the vector in the middle of `list(list(c(NA, NA)))`.
- Since the `(1-p)/2` probability has two candidate results, I'm using a `list` structure with all of the candidates included. For this one, it is `list(c(1,0),c(0,1))`; if you had more possibilities, for example, you could just add the new candidate results inside of that inner list and it would be considered. Since `p`'s results are deterministic, it's just `list(c(1,1))`, in which case it is always returned when `p` is met.
- Since `p` and `(1-p)/2` are not guaranteed to be in order, I have to do a small dance: The list of options (`opts)` need to be ordered such that `list(c(1,1))` always corresponds to `p`, and `list(c(1,0), c(0,1))` always corresponds to `(1-p)/2`, ergo the `[order(ps)]` within the list.
- From there, we use `findInterval` on a random number (from [0,1]) and use it to index on `opts`. If the random number is within `p`, then the element of `opts` corresponding to `p` is returned; if it is within `(1-p)/2`, then the appropriate element of `opts` is returned. The `findInterval` here will always return a value between 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. It's very new-Rer friendly! I learn a lot from it and it solves the problem!